# Amazon RDS free tier database not showing up for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-rds

When I go to create an RDS database, the db.t2.micro database is not showing up for PostgreSQL. [image]

I have the "Include previous generation classes" box checked. The instance type is showing for MySQL but not PostgreSQL.

Comment: Changing the version of PostgreSQL to older version might work, if you are using the newest.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Postgres 12 and lower can run Free Tier, anything above 12 cannot

Comment: True! You will also need to select **Include previous generation classes**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves my problem

Answer (score 8):

I think when aws adds a new version of database, it offers only the old version as a free tier. Currently postgres 13 is available but only lower than 13 has free tier

[image]

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL 13 is [not supported on T2 generation machines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Support). Use a lower version of PostgreSQL to used

[image]